# What hash is using in Sitecore image resizing?

Tags: sitecore

I found that in release notes there is an information that since 7.5 sitecore uses hash when it renders images for security purposes:

> When the feature is enabled, Sitecore automatically signs image URLs
>   that are rendered by the pipeline and adds a hash value to the query
>   string. When processing an incoming media request, image
>   resizing/scaling is skipped if any of the relevant query string
>   parameters in the image URL have been altered or any extra resizing
>   parameters have been appended to the URL. In these cases, Sitecore
>   returns the original, unaltered image.

Do you know what exactly is it hash? Is it hash of an entire url of an image or only of parameters ? What algorithms is using in this hash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sitecore adds hash value based on the `Media.RequestProtection.SharedSecret` value and list of paramters defined in `protectedMediaQueryParameters` setting.

Yes, it does hash the entire url of an image (from what I remember it skips the host name and selects only parameters defined in the setting mentioned above).

By default it uses `SHA1` algorithm.

More information can be found in `Sitecore.Media.RequestProtection.config`.

You can also read `Media request protection` section of the Sitecore 7.5 release notes here: [Release History for Sitecore 7.5](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog.aspx) and blog post from [Sean Holmesby](https://twitter.com/seanholmesby) here: [Images not Resizing in Sitecore 7.5, Sitecore 8.0](http://www.seanholmesby.com/images-not-resizing-in-sitecore-7-5-sitecore-8-0/)